# How to filter string date?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, filtering

I'm working on a date, which i need to filter because the data was too big. This is the code i tried so far.

```
string value = Datetime.Now.tostring("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime fromdate;
fromdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime todate;
todate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

 if((value >= fromdate) && (value <= todate))
{
//filtered items
}
```

The Error always say's

> Operator >= cannot be applied to operand of type string and System datetime

In which part of my code is wrong ?

Comment: Why do you parse the DateTime variables to string? You should compare the actual Dates

Comment: @SteveZ I'm making a new format of date without a time.

Comment: For comparison you can use `DateTime.Now.Date` and `fromdate.Date`. This includes only the date (the time is 00:00:00)

Comment: @Ilorra Even if you are using the "new format" why are you parsing the DateTime and then using it for comparison. Use `date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` for displaying purposes only.

Comment: value and todate are always equal and fromdate isalways less than value so the if condition is always true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't need to parse or convert date, you can deal with date directly

```
DateTime val = DateTime.Now.Date;

DateTime fromdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).Date;

DateTime todate = DateTime.Now;

if((val >= fromdate) && (val <= todate))
{
//filtered items
  Console.WriteLine("do something");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert to a date by using [`DateTime.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8) Method:

```
if ((DateTime.Parse(value) >= fromdate && ((DateTime.Parse(value) <= todate))
```

This code works fine:

```
string value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime fromdate;
fromdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
DateTime todate;
todate = DateTime.Now;

if ((DateTime.Parse(value) >= fromdate && ((DateTime.Parse(value) <= todate))))
{
    //filtered items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this line compile ?

```
fromdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You are defining **fromdate** as **DateTime** and trying to assign a string to it

```
DateTime fromdate;
fromdate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Same applies to **toDate**

Answer (score 0):

```
var now = Datetime.Now;
var value = now.Date;
var fromdate = now.AddDays(-2).Date;
var todate = now.Date;

if((value >= fromdate) && (value <= todate))
{
    //filtered items
}
```

This can be simpler because value and todate are always the same and value is always more than fromdate. So the if condition is always true.